# How to configure Active Directory (ADFS) sign-on for a web application in multiple environments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that uses ADFS for sign-on.  The following is an extract from the Startup.Auth.cs:

```
private static readonly string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
private static readonly string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
        new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Wtrealm = Startup.realm,
            MetadataAddress = Startup.adfsMetadata,         
        });
}
```

My knowledge of ADFS is somewhat limited, but I understand that the **Wtrealm** value that I pass above is used by the ADFS server to identify my application.

However, the web-application exists in multiple environments: Dev, QA and PROD.  The same group of people need to have access to both the DEV and QA environment and so ideally, I'd like to use the same ADFS setup for these environments.

Is this possible/recommended?  If so, what's the best approach (I'm not sure if either of these are even possible)

- Rather than have the Wtrealm be a URL (that's tied to the application in a specific environment) can it be a unique string token that identifies the application, where ever is?  This specific value would then be passed by the application when in either the DEV or QA environment.
- Alternatively, can ADFS be set up so that for a single web application it recognizes multiple Wtrealm values?  Our web application in DEV and QA can then pass their environment-specific URLs and our IT department only need to set this up once in the ADFS server.

Answer (score 0):

wtrealm is just a string - not a URL - that matches the identifier in the ADFS RP.

So have three wtrealm and three RP.

https://appdev.co.nz

https://apptest.co.nz

etc.

Comment: But the examples you provide are all urls....  I go this working by using the URL of our application.